# Reflection - Why can't I access this HttpRequest property?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, httprequest

I am using the following method to output objects with their properties. It works great with most objects, but throws when I pass a HttpRequest object.

```
public static string ConvertToXML(object obj)
{
        if (!obj.GetType().IsPrimitive && obj.GetType() != typeof(String) && obj.GetType() != typeof(Decimal))
        {
            List<string> properties = new List<string>();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
            {
                string name = descriptor.Name;
                object value = descriptor.GetValue(obj);
                properties.Add(xmlify(name, value));
            }
            if (properties.Count == 0)
                return obj.ToString();
            else
                return xmlify(obj, string.Concat(properties));
        }
        else
            return obj.ToString();
}
```

It throws an error in this line:

`descriptor.GetValue(obj);`

The error (sorry, only have the german version :/):

`Der Eigenschaftenaccessor HttpChannelBinding für das System.Web.HttpRequest-Objekt hat folgende Ausnahme verursacht: Die Operation wird auf dieser Plattform nicht unterstützt.`

It says that the Property accessor for the HTTPChannelBinding property does not support the operation on this platform.

Why is that?

Comment: Have you considered using `obj.GetType().GetProperties()`? Then you have a different method call, `property.GetValue(obj, null)`, which may have some underlying difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM ;-) [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpchannelbinding.aspx) that:

> `PlatformNotSupportedException` — The current `HttpWorkerRequest` object is not a `System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest` object or a System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc object.

You should not assume that reading a value of generally any property can't throw an exception.

Comment: So what would I do with a situation like this? Catch the exception and move on?

Comment: That depends on the unique semantics of your code. Most likely catch it, log it/ignore it and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I think MSDN gives you more info:

> Throws PlatformNotSupportedException, if The current HttpWorkerRequest object is not a System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest object or a System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc object.

It should work on Windows Vista (SP1)/ Windows 7 or Windwods 2008 Server (except core).
This may be your Problem.

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpchannelbinding.aspx)