# Reflection - Best way to output any object?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, typedescriptor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TypeDescriptor.GetProperties() vs Type.GetProperties()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402239/typedescriptor-getproperties-vs-type-getproperties)

If I wanted a method which takes a random object and outputs (or otherwise retrieves) every contained Property, which would be the most elegant and robust road to take?

This question is resulting from my prior question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124870/reflection-why-cant-i-access-this-httprequest-property) and a comment proposing an alternate method.

- The way I did it before, using the `TypeDescriptor` and `PropertyDescriptor` class:

  ```
  public static void extract(object obj)
  {
      List<string> properties = new List<string>();
      foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
      {
          string name = descriptor.Name;
          object value = descriptor.GetValue(obj);
          properties.Add(name + " = " value);
      }
      if (properties.Count == 0)
          output(obj.ToString());
      else
          output(obj, string.Concat(properties));
  }
  ```
- The proposed alternative, using Type.GetProperties():

  ```
  public static void extract(object obj)
  {
      List<string> properties = new List<string>();
      foreach (PropertyInfo property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
      {
          string name = property.Name;
          object value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
          properties.Add(name + " = " value);
      }
      if (properties.Count == 0)
          output(obj.ToString());
      else
          output(obj, string.Concat(properties));
  }
  ```

I haven't worked with Reflection so far and don't really see how those two differ. Are there any advantages from one to the other? 
Is there another (better) way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string Extract<T>(this T theObject)
    {
        return string.Join(
            ",",
            new List<string>(
                from prop in theObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                where prop.CanRead
                select string.Format("{0} = {1}",
                prop.Name,
                prop.GetValue(theObject, null))).ToArray());
    }
}
```